# Redis : How to set one key equal to the value of another key?

Tags: database, redis

Is there any quick command in REDIS which allows me to do the following

I want to set the Value of key Y equal to the value of Key X .

How do I go about doing this from the Redis Client .

I use the standard Redis-cli client .

Basically I am looking for some equivalent of the following -

```
 Y.Val() = X.Val()
```

Comment: Answers to this question are limited to duplicate a key of STRING type. However, since Redis 2.6, a more generic solution is to use the `DUMP` and `RESTORE` commands to do the job. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479543/duplicate-a-key-in-redis/53481769#53481769) for detail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with a Lua script:

```
redis.call('SET', KEYS[2], redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])); return 1;
```

1. KEYS1 is the source key
2. KEYS2 is the target key

The example below uses [SCRIPT LOAD](http://redis.io/commands/script-load) to create the script and invokes it using [EVALSHA](http://redis.io/commands/eval) passing the following arguments:

1. The SHA1 returned from the script load
2. a 2 for the number of keys that will be passed
3. The source key
4. The target key.

Output:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> set src.key XXX
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get src.key
"XXX"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> SCRIPT LOAD "redis.call('SET', KEYS[2], redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])); return 1;"
"1119c244463dce1ac3a19cdd4fda744e15e02cab"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> EVALSHA 1119c244463dce1ac3a19cdd4fda744e15e02cab 2 src.key target.key
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get target.key
"XXX"
```

It does appear to be a lot of stuff compared to simply doing a GET and then s SET, but once you've loaded the script (and memorized the SHA1) then you can reuse it repeatedly.

Comment: A COPY command has been introduced since the version 6.2

`
SET dolly "sheep"
COPY dolly clone
GET clone
`

Answer (score 13):

If you dont want script loading then below will work as a single command.

```
   127.0.0.1:6379> eval "return redis.call('SET', KEYS[2], redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]))" 2 key1 key2
   OK
```

Note that key1 value should be already set else you will get the below error

> Lua redis() command arguments must be strings or integers

So check like below and set

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GET key1
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> SET key1 hello
OK
```

Now it will work.

If you want copy map to another new map key

```
eval "return redis.call('HMSET', KEYS[2], unpack(redis.call('HGETALL', KEYS[1])))" 2 existingMapKey newMapKey
```

One more way is while inserting time itself you can insert the value to two keys using MSET.

```
redis> MSET key1 "Hello" key2 "Hello"
"OK"
redis> GET key1
"Hello"
redis> GET key2
"Hello"
```

Ofcource this will not solve the issue of copying when the key is already created.

Also note that there is no way in redis more than one key is referring the same value object. All these workaround will create duplicate value objects. So if one of the value is updated will not reflect in another value object.

Answer (score 6):

Since 6.2.0 you have a COPY command :

https://redis.io/commands/copy

Comment: Welcome to SO. Link-only answers are not acceptable for SO. Please repost this as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no quick command to do this. You have to `GET` the value of the source key, and then `SET` the value of the new key.

Source: http://redis.io/commands#string

Comment: When the value is simple like "hello world" then it is easy to use get/set. But when the values are complex to copy paste in cli, it is better to go with above lua solution.