# Duplicate a key in redis

Tags: redis, key, stackexchange.redis, redis-cli

Can I duplicate a key using the redis-cli connected, is there any command predefined in redis or not?

Duplicate FSS_SYSAGENT to FSS_SYSAGENTDuplicate.

10.44.112.213:6403> hgetall FSS_SYSAGENT

1) "SYSTEM_01"
2) "{\"port\":\"4407\",\"ipAddress\":\"10.44.112.213\",\"symbolicName\":\"SYSTEM_01\",\"eventLogEnabled\":\"1110\",\"status\":1,\"wcPort\":\"6029\",\"activeSystem\":\"N\",\"createdBy\":\"\",\"createdDate\":\"2018-11-20 13:11:16\",\"modifiedBy\":\"\",\"modifiedDate\":\"\",\"institution\":\"FSS\",\"delFlag\":0,\"accessID\":0,\"rowCount\":0,\"endCount\":0}"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis : How to set one key equal to the value of another key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10891213/redis-how-to-set-one-key-equal-to-the-value-of-another-key)

Comment: @UroshT. not a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [DUMP](https://redis.io/commands/dump) and [RESTORE](https://redis.io/commands/restore) commands to duplicate the key:

1. use the `DUMP` command to serialize the value of a key.
2. use the `RESTORE` command to restore the serialized value to another key.

You can wrap these two steps into a Lua script:

```
-- duplicate.lua
local src = KEYS[1]
local dest = KEYS[2]

local val = redis.call('DUMP', src)
if val == false then
    return 0
else
    -- with RESTORE command, you can also set TTL for the new key, and use the [REPLACE] option to set the new key forcefully. 
    redis.call('RESTORE', dest, 0, val)
    return 1
end
```

Run the Lua script with redis-cli: `./redis-cli --eval duplicate.lua FSS_SYSAGENT FSS_SYSAGENTDuplicate ,`

**UPDATE**

Since Redis 6.2.0, you can use the [COPY](https://redis.io/commands/copy) command to do the job.

Comment: while connecting redis-cli we need to mention the ip , port and password with these arguments ??

Comment: Its working by giving  -  /redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379-a password --eval duplicate.lua FSS_SYSAGENT FSS_SYSAGENTDuplicate